# sending data to an axios http request from function parameter

Tags: axios

```js
let name = "myname"
function updateTodo(name) {
    axios.put('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
        title: name,
        completed:true
    })
    .then(res=>showOutput(res))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

I just wanted to send name variable as a function parameter to title data and it shows me that am sending empty data on how to fix this one.

Comment: did you check the value of `name` right before you call `axios.put`?

Comment: yes but it's not working give me an exmple like a code snippet to how you use it

Comment: Hey Makuza!  Can you share how are you calling this function? Are you calling the function as `updateTodo(name);` or `updateTodo();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send `JSON` in an HTTP request body, remember to set the header `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

E.g:

```js
const body = {
    title: name,
    completed: true
};

axios.put('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', body,  {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.
Enjoy!